# Changing input field value while writing

Tags: javascript, php, validation, input, str-replace

Let's say I have a input field

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="filename">
```

and do write something like this:

> Hällo

**Is it possible to check while writing if that field has a the letter `ä` and change it to an `a` while writing ?**

So far, I built this:

```
$search  = array('ä', 'Ä');
$replace = array('ae', 'Ae');

$project = str_replace($search, $replace, $input);
```

Comment: Yes and no, you cannot use php for this only and need to use jQuery / AJAX for this to work, however, i'd recommend only using jQuery / JS as it is cable of doing what you desire without having to execute a AJAX call every time a user writes a character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't do this with PHP, you would do it with Javascript:

```
var el = document.getElementById("filename");
el.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    var replace = ['ä','å'];
    var replacewith = 'a';
    var replace1 = ['ö'];
    var replacewith1 = 'o';
    replace.forEach(function(letter){
        el.value = el.value.replace(letter, replacewith);
    });
    replace1.forEach(function(letter){
        el.value = el.value.replace(letter, replacewith1);
    });
});
```

Add `id="filename"` to the input element for this to work. You can add as many letters to the replace array as you would like.
You can also add more arrays to replace letters.

https://jsfiddle.net/dek5as1x/1

**Edit: Solution for several letters**

```
var el = document.getElementById("filename");
el.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    var replaces = [['ä','å'],['ö','ø'],['ï','ì'],['ü','ù','û'],['ë','ê']];
    var replacewith = ['a','o','i','u','e'];
    replaces.forEach(function(letterGroup, index){
        letterGroup.forEach(function(letter){
            el.value = el.value.replace(letter, replacewith[index]);
        });
    });
});
```

Here you add a new array (`[]`) to replaces. Then you add all the letters to that array that should be turned into the same letter to that array. Example: `['ê','ë','è']`. Then you add the letter to the replacewith array. It is important that the letter comes to replace the letters in the array has the same index as the corresponding array in replaces.
This solution should be a little cleaner for when you have lots of letters to replace.

Comment: Ty it works so far great. Do you know a solution to write the replace in a better way I have like 10 letters which I do want to change while writing and chaining those variables does not look so good I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this using PHP because PHP is serverside.

But you can do this using JavaScript.
Try:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function replace() {
var input = document.getElementById("filename");
input.value = input.value.replace("ä","a");
}
<script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="filename" onchange="replace()">
```